# Snipping tool javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am searching for a JavaScript library that allows me to draw a square selection box onto an image in browser. As a result, I'd like to have the coordinates of the selection box on the image. Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I build it myself. If anyone else has such a requirement:

```
npm i dragsnip
```